# Bitmap of linearLayout doesn't take the all screen, only until the childviews stop. Why?

Tags: android, android-layout, drawing, android-linearlayout, screenshot

So i'm converting my linearLayout to a bitmap like this :

```
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

    view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());

    view.buildDrawingCache(true);

    Bitmap bm = view.getDrawingCache();
```

It works great, except that it only capture if there is a view, so for example, if i have some childviews until the middle of my LinearLayout the bitmap will of the size of the half of a layout (with all the informations in it)
What i want is to take always the full screenshot, so in my example the bitmap will have the full size and the second half will be empty ! But not cropped from half. Help ? Anyone ?

Comment: Which other views ? I don't have other views, let's say i have only views until the middle, but i still want the bitmap to be the size of the all screen (or layout).

Comment: What is that 'view' in your code? Is it your layout? How does your Layout look like?

Comment: view is my linearlayout, and my layout look like the most simple linearlayout possible, vertically multiple elements until the middle. My linearlayout is supposed to match parent both in width and height.